# MINICOM TTY communication and HEX conversion

Tags: linux, bash, unix, tty, minicom

I'm trying to send information through minicom to a device through TTY.

The interesting thing is that when I enter let's say "a" I see "4f", which in ASCII should be "61" hex, or "97" decimal. Other examples are:

```
b = 27 
c = ce
1 = 67
2 = 33
3 = e6
```

They definitely do not correspond to their ASCII counterparts.

Obviously I am doing something wrong. I wonder - is there a way to figure the "formula" for translating the characters to hex.

Please help!

Comment: You said you see a = 4f, yet your table shows 1 = 4f. They both show as 4f?

Comment: @Lkabo my bad, sorry, 1="67"

Comment: Do you have your parity, data bits and stop bits set correctly? I know some microcotrolers use strange combinations. I have some TI controllers that use N-8-2 (instead of the usual N-8-1). Improper TTY settings can lead to the translation errors.